# Why is Google People API giving error 403 "permission denied" recently?

Tags: permission-denied, api-key, google-people-api, google-api-explorer

I'm trying to do a really basic Google People API request...

`https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/108498888227655418560?personFields=photos&key=XXX` (API key redacted)

It produces the error...

`{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}`

I've successfully tested the API key before with the same type of request. It's a key from our Google Developer Console called "Browser key (auto created by Google Service)".

---

I also tried the same request using the [Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) using API key authentication, same result...

[image: Google API Explorer error]

The API Explorer uses a demo API key, so the problem isn't the key it seems.

---

Could it be `photos` is no longer part of a Google user's public profile data? I don't think so, since you can go see the user's profile photo (even when completely logged out of Google) at...
http://profiles.google.com/108498888227655418560

**Maybe the People API is just broken?** It was definitely working just a couple of days ago (Feb 5th 2018).

Comment: Note: I get the same error with numerous Google user IDs, and on different devices at different locations.

Comment: There was a bug in the People API that broke it briefly for unauthenticated requests. This should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks Amos! Not sure about briefly but yr quick fix is much appreciated https://imgur.com/a/eHxUo

Answer (score 0):

Google People API was actually broken.

Comment: is? I am here today with the same issue. On some requests it shows the photo just fine, on others I get 403.

Comment: If it was working perfectly for you previously and now is intermittent then it may well be broken again. Tweeting @googledevs might help?

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty certain it's broken (again)... I'm not sure if it ever worked perfectly because this is a new app I'm developing. I've seen broken images countless times and it keeps bugging me but every time I investigate it's the same thing: the copied URL just works for me ina new browser tab and in the network tab I see 403 responses for the broken images.

Comment: I did not know about @googledevs, might try that, thanks!